# Не отображается таблица в Wordpress если ее выводить посредством php

Tags: php, wordpress

При попытке вывести таблицу через `[exec] echo %таблица%; [/exec]` ничего не выводится, при том, если выводить обычный текст, например "test" этот текст выводится корректно.
На денвере, например, апач вообще не хочет отображать страничку и тупо ее "роняет" т.е. постоянно сбрасывает соединение

Answer (score 0):

Судя по комментариям Вы хотите вывести содержимое таблицы из тела WP-поста используя специальный шорткод.

Думаю, что можно вывести обычным для WP способом, просто через Ваш шорткод:

```
[exec]
    global $wpdb; // обращаемся к глобальному $wpdb
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table" ); // table = имя таблицы
    foreach ($posts as $post)
        var_dump($post); // Скорее всего это массив или объект
[/exec]
```

Comment: Я Вас понял, но мне необходимо вывести не табличку из БД, а табличку которую я сам нарисовал в HTML

Comment: @Kernozz Таблица генерируется на PHP? Ибо если это обычная таблица, то PHP тут не нужен и можно просто поместить код без всяких [exec]

Comment: Совершенно верно, значения в таблице генерируются в PHP а тот берет данные из БД
Сама таблица может быть статична и без всяких [exec] обойдется, а вот значения в ней - динамичны

Answer (score -2):

Решается все костылем и очень некрасиво, как по мне, просто теперь я в каждую ячейку таблицы пишу `[exec] код [/exec]`